# JavaScript Uncaught Type Error with dataTables.editable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use jquery.dataTables.editable in an application I am working on and have spent the last 5 hours reading SO posts with similar issues but none of them seem to address why I am seeing the below error. The screenshot shows the scripts that are loaded as well as the error from Chrome DevTools.

[image]

Any Ideas of what I am overlooking here???

After getting a suggestion I did try it as my below screenshot shows but again with the same error about dataTables.

Funny this is as the below screenshot shows, it is being found in the helpers..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the normal datatables plugin as well. It can be found [here](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Still No dice. After doing that I still get the same error no change at all.. Please see edited original post for current setup using what you recommended from that site.